# Add lines of text to subtitle of Xcode UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I am using master/detail template in Xcode. I can add text into the maintitle and the subtitle of the table view.
The subtitle only shows one line of text with ... at the end.
I understand that it is telling me that more text is available.
How would I have it give me 2 or maybe 3 lines of text before the ...   I tried making the cell larger, but that had no affect.
I don't see any parameters that will increase the number of lines.
 thanks

Comment: I think you mean iOS, rather than Xcode don't you?

Answer (score 0):

The default cell give you a label with just one line, if you want change it you will need to create your own custom UITableViewCell and add a label wit the number of lines you need:

[Customizing UITableViewCells](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW18)